# LINQ Query Fails to identify duplicates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have two custom classes.

The first class contains basic data:

```
public class Request
{
    public Request(int lineID, string partNo, int qty, int reasonID, int typeID)
    {
        LineID = lineID;
        PartNo = partNo;
        Qty = qty;
        ReasonID = reasonID;
        TypeID = typeID;
    }
    public int LineID { get; private set; }
    public string PartNo { get; private set; }
    public int Qty { get; internal set; }
    public int ReasonID { get; private set; }
    public int TypeID { get; private set; }
}
```

The second class contains a List of these Request objects, with a signature as follows:

```
public class Requests : IEnumerable<Request>
{
    private List<Request> list;

    public Requests()
    {
        list = new List<Request>();
    }

    public int Add(Request item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            foreach (var x in list.Where(r => 
              (r.LineID == item.LineID) &&
              (r.PartNo == item.PartNo) &&
              (r.ReasonID == item.ReasonID) &&
              (r.TypeID == item.TypeID)))
            {
                x.Qty += item.Qty;
                return list.IndexOf(x);
            }
            list.Add(item);
            return list.Count - 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // other code 
}
```

I am testing my code and adding items is putting new items into the list, but the LINQ query to find duplicates is not working.

If 2 identical items are added to the list, I want my code to be smart enough to simply update the quantity, but it does not seem to be working.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with the LINQ query?

Comment: What is RequestId?  It is not defined in your class.

Comment: Not the answer, but using a `foreach` is pointless since you return on the first iteration.

Comment: @JoelPotter I'd guess from looking at the code that OP is either new to LINQ or doesn't use it very often.

Comment: I would make Request implement IEquatable<Request>, and use list.Contains(item)...

Comment: John: I did not show the very long, complete class. That was a typo that I corrected. Apologies. Others: Yes, I am new to LINQ. Raphael: The quantity value (Qty) would vary between different elements.

Comment: @jp2code, the code looks like it should function the way you desire.  Can you update your question to show us a few lines of code that consumes your method and demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's relatively tricky to follow what's going on. A short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: @KirkWoll: I'm not sure how. My web application's code behind simply adds an item to the `Requests` class. I have a breakpoint set at this spot, and when I step into it - all of the values look to be equal.

Comment: @jp2code, but it doesn't seem like an issue with the web application.  As Jon suggested, can't you create a simple console application that calls the `Add` method and passes it a duplicate and repro that way?  If so, you could post that code and we could try it.

Comment: @jp2code You're implementation is "not that nice", but is logically correct. I would look at the usages of the "Requests" class. Are you sure you're using the same instance of Requests between your failing cases ? Cause if you don't, you're working on a new list each time...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I had originally thought about that (happens a lot with web forms), but dismissed it whenever the debugger showed items in my list that were equal but still not falling through to the `x.Qty += item.Qty` method ...but LINQ does some strange things in the debugger, so you could be right. I would like to see a much nicer looking way of accomplishing my objective. My console app testing this works fine, BTW.

Comment: @jp2code, you can actually set the breakpoint *inside* your lambda (after the `r =>`).  If you do this, you can compare property by property and see why it's not returning true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone tell me what is wrong with the LINQ query?

Theoretically it looks OK. I think we need to know more information about your data to be able to find out why it isn't working as you expect. Does the combination of `LineID`, `PartNo`, `ReasonID`, and `TypeID` uniquely distinguish an item? Since `PartNo` is a string, are the values case-insensitive (your comparison is case-sensitive)?

> If 2 identical items are added to the list, I want my code to be smart enough to simply update the quantity, but it does not seem to be working.

For this I would suggest a different approach. Consider overriding `Equals()` on your `Request` type. Then your `Add` method can just check if the list already contains the item, incrementing the quantity if so and adding it if not:

```
var idx = list.IndexOf(item);
if(idx != -1)
{
    list[idx].Qty += item.Qty;
}
else
{
    list.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `Request` implement `IEquatable<Request>`, because [this is what `IndexOf` uses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx):

```
public bool Equals(Request other) {
    return other != null && (this.LineID == other.LineID) && (this.PartNo == other.PartNo) && (this.ReasonID == other.ReasonID) && (this.TypeID == other.TypeID);
}
```

Then:

```
public int Add(Request item) {
    if (item != null)
    {
        int ind = list.IndexOf(item);

        if (ind == -1)
        {
            list.Add(item);
            return list.Count - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            list[ind].Qty += item.Qty;
            return ind;
        }                
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the method by materializing LINQ query. For example:

```
public int Add(Request item) {
    if (item != null) {
      foreach (var x in list.Where(r => 
        (r.LineID == item.LineID) &&
        (r.PartNo == item.PartNo) &&
        (r.ReasonID == item.ReasonID) &&
        (r.TypeID == item.TypeID)
        ).ToList()) {
        x.Qty += item.Qty;
        return list.IndexOf(x);
      }
      list.Add(item);
      return list.Count - 1;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

But, because your Requests must be unique, you can use this

```
public int Add(Request item)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        var req = list.SingleOrDefault(r =>
                              (r.LineID == item.LineID) &&
                              (r.PartNo == item.PartNo) &&
                              (r.ReasonID == item.ReasonID) &&
                              (r.TypeID == item.TypeID)
            );
        if(req!=null)
        {
            req.Qty += item.Qty;
            return list.IndexOf(req);
        }
        list.Add(item);
        return list.Count - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```